# Java Programs Using GUIs Self Terminate on Windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, user-interface, terminate

Whenever I work on Java programs involving GUIs on Windows (I used 8 and now use 8.1 - same problem), they self terminate without warning or explanation.  I can't find any information on this anywhere... The same program will run fine when I boot into Linux on my computer, but never on Windows - I've ran it from Eclipse and the terminal.  Please help!

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class DisplayGUI {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        System.out.println("1");
        JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
        System.out.println("2");

    } 
}
```

^ This just prints 1 and terminates every time.

My confusion is only why does this print "1" and "2" on Linux but "1" on Windows.
Edited to show a "non-trivial" example:
The reason I'm asking is because Windows reacting to my GUI like this is making an assignment inconvenient.

For example, I have
...

```
public Main( ) {
    maze = new MyMaze();
    maze.generateMaze( rows, columns );
    path = maze.solveMaze( );   
    System.out.println("1");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame( "CS2321 Final Program Maze");
    System.out.println("2");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setSize( 1024, 768 );
    frame.setContentPane( this );
    frame.setVisible( true );
}
```

...

Where with the rest of the program, the GUI appears on Linux but not on Windows...

Comment: [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: The fact that the `JFrame` is never made visible, means that the EDT has not been started and the only thread that is likely running is the main thread, which called `main`, which once it exists, will allow the JVM to terminate...You might, also, like to take look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) as well as the tutorials linked by Reimeus...

Comment: The JFrame is made visible later in the program (I didn't paste it) - I am very familiar with Java GUIs and this program works fine on Linux.  Though the JFrame is made visible later in main(), "2" will never be printed and the program terminates immediately.

Comment: Sounds like you have an uncaught exception, because your example code prints `1` and `2` just fine for me. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Running just the follow below results in only "1" being printed and termination:

import javax.swing.*;

public class DisplayGUI {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    System.out.println("1");
    JFrame mainWindow = new JFrame();
    System.out.println("2");

} 
}

It is the same as in my question code example.  My confusion is that this prints 1 and 2 when I test it on Linux on my computer, but only 1 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: *"..but only 1 on Windows 8.1."*  It's a trite and pointless example IMO.  Construct the frame on the EDT and set it visible for any sort of real test.

Comment: Also, please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.